# Einstein Engagement Frequency understanding

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I am having issues understanding how the Einstein Engagement Frequency dashboard work. I see we have a high % of consumers who are oversaturated but I cannot see the reason why (apart from the number of emails that are sent to that segment).

According to the documentation, I should be able to find the Data Extensions Einstein_MC_EMAIL_Frequency_Undersaturation and Einstein_MC_Email_Frequency_Oversaturation in MC but I didn't.

In addition to that, since the last release, I cannot see the table where the user can adapt the saturation rules.

Could someone provide any feedback on this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Einstein Engagement Frequency was updated in Oct 2020, with a new, improved, ML model. The older version of Einstein Engagement Frequency predicted a more general, overall email send frequency range that was applied to all your subscribers/contacts. For eg. "Einstein recommends sending 7 - 10 emails to all your contacts within a 30-day period."

The new, and improved version predicts the optimal email send frequencies for every single contact at the individual level. It does this by optimizing for maximizing the message open rates, and minimizing the unsubscribes. Now, every single contact in your business unit has their own individual preferred frequency range (based on their past engagement). Manually setting saturation rules (like capping frequency at 4 emails per week), is not a true AI-driven solution and has its limitations. There still could be contacts within your BU who might be saturated at 4 emails per week, because their open rates are maximum at 2 emails per week and begin to drop after that. Einstein predicts this ideal send frequency for every single contact, ensuring higher open rates, and avoids causing message fatigue for your contacts.

There is a new 'Frequency Split' that you can use while designing journeys on Journey Builder, and in real-time Einstein can now intelligently segment your contacts based on their preferred frequency. You can try reducing the number of emails that are sent to your saturated segment of contacts, and increase the frequency for your undersaturated segment as you have an opportunity to send them more messages and drive up open rates.

Please see this [trailhead live video](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/live/videos/a2r3k000001n2AI/personalization-made-simple-with-einstein-engagement-frequency/) for more details.

Comment: does it work across business units? For example, does business unit B take into account subscriber saturation in business unit A?

Comment: No, this is not done across business units today. Contacts in business unit A are evaluated based on the messages they've received from BU A and are separate from the saturation in BU B.

Comment: Thank you Ajaay!